# Error installing scrapy in python on ubuntu using pip

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, scrapy, pip

I am trying to install scrapy using pip on ubuntu but i am getting this error

> Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_build_aarsh/Twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uaGXyu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_aarsh/Twisted Storing debug log for failure in /home/aarsh/.pip/pip.log

I tried to install twisted first and then install scrapy but it says that twisted is already installed.

Comment: and what does that pip.log says ?

Comment: @dnit13

Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/T/Twisted/Twisted-10.1.0.winxp32-py2.5.msi#md5=b5359483b3e9cee67dc87b40d41c6c3f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/twisted/); unknown archive format: .msi

Comment: Now this is fishy, since you are on ubuntu why is your pip trying to install msi? which is used for windows.